# Material-UI BottomNavigationItem URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-design, material-ui

UI on a react component. I have a `<BottomNavigationItem />` component. This actually renders as an `<button>`. How can I actually make it render/navigate to a URL?

```
class FooterNavigation extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedIndex: 0,
  };

  select = (index) => this.setState({selectedIndex: index});

  render() {
    return (
        <footer className="mdl-mini-footer">
            <Paper zDepth={1}>
            <BottomNavigation selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}>
            <BottomNavigationItem
                label="Reviews"
                icon={reviewIcon}
                onClick={() => this.select(0)}
            />
            </BottomNavigation>
            </Paper>
        </footer>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can just add `containerElement={<Link to="/home"/>}` don't forget to import `Link` from `react-router-dom`

So it will be like this:

```
   <BottomNavigationItem
                containerElement={<Link to="/home"/>}
                label="Reviews"
                icon={reviewIcon}
                onClick={() => this.select(0)}
            />
```